# Org (version 7.9) converts periods and hyphens in tables to 0

Tags: emacs, org-mode, tabular

I am using the Org mode that comes with Emacs 24.3, and I am having an issue that when Org creates a table from the result of a code block it is replacing characters like '-' and '.' with 0 (integer zero). Then when I pass the table to another code block that's expecting a column of strings I get type errors etc.

I haven't been able to find anything useful, as it seems to be practically un-Googleable. Has anyone had the same problem? If I update to the latest version of org-mode, will that fix it?

**EDIT:**

I updated to Org 8.2 and this problem seems to have gone away. Now I have another (related) problem, where returning a table with a cell containing a string consisting of one double quote character ('"' in python) messes something up; Org added 2 extra columns to the table, one had something like

```
(quote (quote )  ())
```

in it. The reason my tables have things like this in them is that I'm working with part-of-speech tags from natural language data.

It's pretty obvious Org is doing some stuff to try to interpret the table contents, and not dealing well with meta characters. Technically I think these are bugs where Org should be dealing better with unexpected input.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is a minimal reproduction with Org 7.9.3f (system Python is 3.4):

```
#+TBLNAME: table
| DT | The |
| .  | .   |
| -  | -   |


#+BEGIN_SRC python :var table=table
return table
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| DT | The |
|  0 |   0 |
|  0 |   0 |
```

Incidentally, Org does not like the '"' character *at all*, in tables or in code blocks (I just get a "End of file during parsing" message when the above table has a cell with just '"' in it). It's probably just better to avoid it altogether, so I think my problem is solved. If nobody wants to add anything, I'll answer this myself in a day or so.

Comment: I'm on version 8.2.6 of `org-mode` (Emacs 24.3.1), and I can't reproduce this problem; tried with a `sh` code block containing a bunch of calls to `echo` producing various combinations of `-` and `.`. What language(s) are you using in your code blocks?

Comment: I'm using python; just a code block with :var table=<table> and return table inside is sufficient to show the problem sometimes. But actually (I will update the question in a sec) I updated org to 8.2 through ELPA and the specific problem disappeared. (Now I have a different problem...) So something between 7.9 and 8.2 changed that affected it, but I don't know if it was a bug or something unrelated.